# Can't run two servers in Amazon EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to run two servers, one apache server on port 8080 and another one shiny R server on port 3838.  What I am observing is that, I can run only one server instance at a time.  When I start one, the other instance dies and shuts down.   It this a limitation with this instance (micro instance).  Has anyone experienced this before.

Comment: Er... any error or log messages?

Comment: Are you running two separate instance? or two services on one instance?

Answer (score 0):

613MB of memory is not a lot. Most likely a memory issue. Check you logs for out of memory errors. If possible, running separate servers on separate instances simplifies debugging and memory management.